# How to ping a computer if the computer name starts with dash "-"

Tags: networking, ping

How to ping a computer if the computer name starts with dash "-"

Comment: i wouldn't recommend closing this question. Yes it's not directly programming related, but it could be. Sumesh might be writing a program which checks if a server is online or not. In any case, the answer will be short and definitive.

Answer (score 15):

On *nix, use a "--" to allow an argument beginning with a dash:

```
ping -- -funkyhost
```

(This probably won't help on Windows, though, because Windows command-line parsing is kind of rudimentary)

On another side note, well-formed DNS names are not allowed to start with a hyphen.

Comment: +1 for noting that valid RFC-compliant hostnames cannot start (or end) with a hyphen.

Comment: Same with _underscore_, you can have it in a Windows computer name, but it's not an RFC-compliant host name, so I stay away from using it.

Answer (score 2):

**On Windows:**

Try escaping out the dash with a backslash ('\') character:

```
ping \-<hostname>.<domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft Windows, 
use Alt+0151 — Longer Dash

**To ping a pc name called "-Quant-"**

1. cmd
2. type ping
3. press and hold Alt then type 0151 from num-pad, release Alt
4. type Quant
5. press and hold Alt then type 0151 from num-pad, release Alt
6. press enter

Answer (score -1):

What about using an IP address?

Comment: What if you don't know the IP address, or if it is prone to change?